# OpenGL 3.2 VAO creation fails on OS X Maverick

Tags: macos, opengl

I have a program which used to work fine on MAC OS X Lion.It uses OpenGL 3.2 Core profile.Now after I upgraded to Maverick it fails on glGenVertexArrays() right after context setup.The context is being created all right.What has changed in Maverick regarding OpenGL 3.2 setup?

I initialise the context like this:

```
static CGLPixelFormatAttribute attributes[4]={
kCGLPFAAccelerated,  
kCGLPFAOpenGLProfile, 
(CGLPixelFormatAttribute)kCGLOGLPVersion_3_2_Core,
(CGLPixelFormatAttribute)0
};





    _errorCode = CGLChoosePixelFormat(attributes,&_pix,&_num);
    if(_errorCode > 0){

        throw ;
    }
    _errorCode = CGLCreateContext(_pix, NULL, &_context);
    if(_errorCode > 0){

          throw;
    }
    CGLDestroyPixelFormat(_pix);

    _errorCode = CGLSetCurrentContext(_context);
    if(_errorCode > 0){

        throw ;
    }
```

None of these throws an error till I am getting to VAO handle generation.Also glGetError returns some junk.

UPDATE:

I caught the error which is GL_INVALID_FRAMEBUFFER_OPERATION​, 0x0506 .And now it happens when I perform

glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);

when no custom framebuffer is bound.If I call the draw command with custom FBO it does work.My context creation has no display.It is offscreen.Can it be that with the newer implementation Apple enforces display to exist in order to access default FBO? On Lion I did the same and it worked.Btw,the GL version is 4.1.

Comment: There were no changes, but the version that constant will get you is no longer **3.2**. It will get you the newest context version supported by your hardware, it was really rather short-sighted of Apple to put an explicit version number into that constant. The rest of your question is pretty hard to answer/understand, can you show some actual GL API calls?

Comment: Mavericks upgraded the (minimum) core profile to 3.3. Try that?

Comment: You cannot request a specific version in OS X; you just use that *3_2_Core* constant and OS X gives you whatever core profile is available. Honestly, they should have created two constants: `kCGLOGLProfileCore` and `kCGLOGLProfileLegacy`, because having a version number in the constant confuses many people ;)

Comment: Then I have no idea why it fails.It is the same machine with the same GPU.It should support VAO.

Comment: Who says it does not? You have not given any real information here, only that "`glGetError` returns some junk." It is impossible to diagnose your problem from the description.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman  see my updates.There is not much code to show.Right after context creation I just fill a buffer with full screen quad  array, bind it to VAO ,that's it.The draw fails when I am bound to default framebuffer.

Comment: On a whim, does adding `kCGLPFANoRecovery` to the attribute list change anything? There was/may still be a bug related to drawing offscreen in Mavericks that requires this attribute to workaround, but I think it pertains to actual pixel format selection and you would not get as far as context creation if that were your problem. The attribute's *intended* purpose is to prevent software fallback for anything not implemented in hardware, and is rarely necessary.

Comment: Adding a non-zero `kCGLPFAColorSize` might help too, but I cannot explain why that was not necessary in 10.8. The default behavior is such that *"If unspecified, OpenGL chooses a color buffer size that matches the screen."*, obviously if you have no screen that behavior does not make a lot of sense.